# Boundednes, Total Boundedness, and Pointwise Boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of complex-valued functions on a set $X$. I am trying to prove that

> If $\mathcal{F}$ is totally bounded with respect to the uniform metric, then $\mathcal{F}$ is pointwise bounded.

My questions are:

1. Does boundedness (with respect to the uniform metric) of $\mathcal{F}$ imply its pointwise boundedness?
2. If the answer to 1. is "yes", is the condition "$\mathcal{F}$ is totally bounded" too strong for this statement?

Any of your help will be highly appreciated! :)

Comment: Well, what are your definitions of totally bounded and pontwise-bounded? Perhaps you could include that in the body of your question and try to see how one could imply the other, and show where that train of thought leads you.

Comment: @FedePoncio Totally bounded is a notion that's defined for any metric (even uniform) space. Pointwise-bounded (for function) means that  $\{f(x): f \in \mathcal{F}\}$ is bounded for all $x \in X$.

Comment: Yes, but notice how smoothly your answer developed from stating the definitions. They could’ve done similarly. My point was that they could show their work and have the answer be more personalized, while trying to think about it by themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is bounded in the uniform metric $d_\infty$, so that there is some $f_0 \in \mathcal{F}$ and some $N >0$ such that $\mathcal{F} \subseteq B_{d_\infty}(f_0, N)$.

If $x \in X$ then all $|f(x)|, f \in \mathcal{F}$ can be bounded above by $N + |f_0(x)|$, so $\mathcal{F}$ is pointwise bounded.

So 1 and 2: yes. But this is likely a step in Arzela-Ascoli, where we're working with equicontinuous families of continuous function (and then bounded and totally bounded are equivalent again, IIRC). So in isolation it might seem overkill, but in context it's what you have anyway.